# Removing file path from tab name

Tags: windows-xp, sublime-text-2

I just switched to Sublime Text 2 from Notepad++, and I managed to change everything, except for the file path being displayed next to the file name in the tab title if there are two or more more files with the same name. How can I get rid of it?

[image: Sublime Text 2 - File path net to tab title]

Answer (score -2):

Go into the menu, choose Preferences > "Settings - Default".

This will open a configuration file, there is a setting in there which says:

```
"show_full_path": true,
```

You should change this to false, and that should do it!

Comment: It only changes the window title, but not the tab title.